# Find average time between records

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I have the following data in a BigQuery table (call logs) :

| number | called_at | direction | staff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2023-01-02 13:00 | IN | John |
| 1111 | 2023-01-03 12:00 | IN | John |
| 1111 | 2023-01-04 18:00 | OUT | John |
| 2222 | 2023-01-05 12:00 | IN | Mark |
| 3333 | 2023-01-04 08:00 | IN | John |
| 3333 | 2023-01-04 17:00 | IN | John |
| 2222 | 2023-01-07 09:00 | OUT | Mark |
| 3333 | 2023-01-07 15:00 | OUT | John |
| 1111 | 2023-01-09 11:00 | IN | John |
| 1111 | 2023-01-13 18:00 | OUT | John |

How can I get the average time it takes for a given staff to call back numbers.

Or in other words, find using SQL the time difference between INs and OUTs (if any) for a given number and do the average for each staff.

EDIT:
I'm excepting this :

| staff | avg_hour |
| --- | --- |
| John | 78.3 |
| Mark | 45 |

Comment: Are you counting only the number of days by design?

Comment: No it was to simplify the table, I'm counting time between.

Comment: Please show us the result that you would expect for this sample data.

Comment: Why should Mark be listed? He has an IN record from number 2222, and an OUT from number 1111. Should we count this as a call back? Also, should the OUT record from John on 01/04 count as a return to both of the first two calls?

Comment: That was a typo sorry. No it counts only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to first calculate the return time for each call, and then calculate tha average for each staff. You can achieve this with CTE or with a nested query based on the following code, which I'll divide into two queries for clarity, but there's no need to actually create a table.

This query will create a table with only the IN calls, and the first time they have been called back. Since you stated that you're counting time between, and not days, I'm assuming you can't have two in calls at the same time, because if you can, duplicates will disappear as you group the query:

```
CREATE TABLE callbacks AS
SELECT a.number
    , a.called_at
    , a.direction
    , a.staff
    , min(b.called_at) as callback
    , min(b.called_at) - a.called_at as return_time
FROM (select * from your_table where direction = 'IN') a
INNER JOIN (select * from your_table where direction = 'OUT') b
    ON a.number = b.number
        AND a.staff = b.staff
        AND a.called_at <= b.called_at
GROUP BY a.number, a.called_at, a.direction, a.staff
```

Now all you have to do is to count the average time each staff takes to return calls. Be aware that only returned calls are going to be counted, and in your example, both lines 1 and 2 will be counted as returned by line 3.

```
SELECT staff, avg(return_time) AS avg_return_time
FROM callbacks
GROUP BY staff
```

A nested query that achieves this could be:

```
SELECT staff, avg(return_time) AS avg_return_time
FROM (
    SELECT a.number
        , a.called_at
        , a.direction
        , a.staff
        , min(b.called_at) as callback format ddmmyys.
        , min(b.called_at) - a.called_at as return_time
    FROM (select * from your_table where direction = 'IN') a
    INNER JOIN (select * from your_table where direction = 'OUT') b
        ON a.number = b.number
            AND a.staff = b.staff
            AND a.called_at <= b.called_at
    GROUP BY a.number, a.called_at, a.direction, a.staff
)
GROUP BY staff
```

Comment: Why are you creating table? Wouldn't CTE suffice here?

Comment: It would. A nested query would as well. I thought that creating a table to show only the first part of the thought process would make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions instead of self-joining the table.

```
select staff, 
    avg(lead_called_at - called_at) avg_diff 
from (
    select t.*,
        lead(direction) over(partition by number, staff order by called_at) lead_direction,
        lead(called_at) over(partition by number, staff order by called_at) lead_called_at
    from mytable t
) t
where direction = 'IN' and lead_direction = 'OUT'
group by staff
```

`lead()` brings back the direction and timestamp of the "next" call for the same number and staff member. We can then simply filter on IN/OUT transitions and compute the average difference.